# CoreNLP tokenizer/sentence splitter misbehaves on HTML input

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm using the Stanford CoreNLP pipeline from the command line to dependency parse a large document, and it's very important that each line in the document receive its own dependency tree (otherwise other things get unaligned). This pair of lines is currently causing me grief:

```
<!-- copy from here --> <a href="http://strategis.gc.ca/epic/internet/inabc-eac.nsf/en/home"><img src="id-images/ad-220x80_01e.jpg" alt="Aboriginal Business Canada:
Opening New Doors for Your Business" width="220" height="80" border="0"></a> <!-- copy to here --> Small ABC Graphic Instructions 1.
```

This is the command I'm using:

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx1g -Xss515m edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP \ 
     -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse \
     -ssplit.eolonly true \
     -ssplit.newlineIsSentenceBreak always \
     -outputFormat conllu \
     -file "input.txt"
```

And this is the resulting output:

```
1   <!-- copy from here --> _   _   JJ  _   9   amod    _   _
2   <a href="http://strategis.gc.ca/epic/internet/inabc-eac.nsf/en/home">   _   _   JJ  _   9   amod    _   _
3   <img src="id-images/ad-220x80_01e.jpg" alt="Aboriginal Business Canada:
Opening New Doors for Your Business" width="220" height="80" border="0">    _   _   NN  _   9   compound    _   _
4   </a>    _   _   NN  _   9   compound    _   _
5   <!-- copy to here -->   _   _   NN  _   9   compound    _   _
6   Small   _   _   JJ  _   9   amod    _   _
7   ABC _   _   NNP _   9   compound    _   _
8   Graphic _   _   NNP _   9   compound    _   _
9   Instructions    _   _   NNS _   0   root    _   _
10  1   _   _   CD  _   9   nummod  _   _
11  .   _   _   .   _   9   punct   _   _
```

It looks like the newline character inside the quotation marks in the HTML tag is being interpreted as part of the token, rather than as a sentence break. This is peculiar since I'm using the `-ssplit.newlineIsSentenceBreak always` flag, which I would expect would force the parser to split up the HTML code. However, even if I didn't need each line to get its own parse, this behavior is troubling because the resulting file is no longer in valid conllu format, since line 3 has only two tab-separated columns (instead of the required 10) and line 4 has only 9.

One workaround I played with was turning each line in the original file into its own file and then feeding them in with the `-filelist` parameter, but that created too much `stdout` output that slowed things down and clogged the terminal. My attempts to redirect the output to `/dev/null` or turn on a "quiet mode" were met with failure, but that's probably a question for another post.

I tried double-spacing the file, but that didn't help. Preprocessing the text with `sed 's/"/\\"/g'` does fix this problem by destroying the pipeline's ability to recognize this as HTML code, but introduces new ones since the parser presumably wasn't trained on escaped quotation marks.

Obviously this is a weird sentence and I don't expect the output to be parsed sensibly, but I do need it be formatted sensibly. Any tips?

**Update**
It was suggested to me that I try using the cleanxml annotator to get rid of the HTML tag altogether. This reduces the number of lines in the file, which may result in misalignment later, but since the HTML tags aren't getting parsed sensibly anyway it seems independently advantageous to get rid of them. I'll update again later with whether or not this works for my purposes, but I'm open to other suggestions in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems here:

1. The tokenizer will parse as a single token HTML/XML/SGML tags where the quoted value of an attribute is split over lines. Usually this is a good thing - if this were regular text, what it is doing for this example is actually sensible, keeping the whole `img` tag together - but it is disastrous if you are wanting to process text as strictly one sentence per line, as in most machine translation corpora. In this case you want to treat each line as a sentence, even if the original sentence breaking was done wrongly, as here.
2. If a newline was captured in the value of an attribute, it was left as such, and then on output, this destroyed the integrity of at least the line-oriented CoNLL and CoNLL-U output formats.

I've added/changed code to address these problems:

1. There is a new tokenizer option: `-tokenize.options tokenizePerLine`, which will disallow the tokenizer from looking across line boundaries when forming tokens or making tokenization decisions. (This option can be combined in a comma-separated list with all the other `tokenize.options` options.)
2. If a newline is captured in the value of an attribute, then it is mapped to `U+00A0` (non-breaking space). This was already what happened to `U+0020` (space) and is now also done for newlines. This fixes the CoNLL/CoNLL-U output and maintains the correct invariant for Stanford CoreNLP: Tokens may occasionally contain non-breaking spaces, but never space or newline.

This problem is fixed in commit 0a17fe4c0fc4ccfb095f474bf113d1df0c6d17cb on [the CoreNLP github](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP). If you grab that version -- or minimally update the `PTBLexer.class` and `PTBTokenizer.class`, then you will have this new option and should be good. The following command should give you what you want:

`java -cp "*" -Xmx1g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP \
    -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse -ssplit.eolonly true \
    -tokenize.options tokenizePerLine -outputFormat conllu -file "input.txt"`

p.s. I guess you were trying to fix things, but if you're using `-ssplit.eolonly true` then you shouldn't need or see a difference from `-ssplit.newlineIsSentenceBreak always`. Also, we maybe should make it so that turning on `-ssplit.eolonly true` automatically turns on `-tokenize.options tokenizePerLine`, but that is not presently the case....